# Adding an attribute to a ListItem, not rendering styles

Tags: asp.net, css, checkboxlist

I have a checkboxlist on a page as below.

```
   <asp:CheckBoxList runat="server" ID="lstFeatures" RepeatDirection="Vertical"></asp:CheckBoxList>
```

The backend code looks like so.

```
    private void MakeRegionCheckboxes(ReportRegion region, int margin)
    {
        foreach (ReportRegion subregion in region.childRegions)
        {
            ListItem item = new ListItem();
            item.Text = subregion.Name;
            item.Value = subregion.Name;
            item.Selected = subregion.DefaultSelection;
            item.Attributes.Add("style", "margin-left:" + margin.ToString() + "px");
            lstFeatures.Items.Add(item);

            MakeRegionCheckboxes(subregion, margin + 30);
        }
    }
```

When this runs on a blank project, it indents the "subregions" nicely as the style:margin-left:30px gets rendered in a span as you can see.

```
<td>
  <span style="margin-left:30px">
  <input id="lstFeatures_1" type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="lstFeatures$1">
  <label for="lstFeatures_1">Member Information</label>
  </span>
</td>
```

However, when I run the **same** code in my main project it doesn't render the spans and therefore the margin isn't getting set. All I get is this.

```
<td>
   <input id="ctl00_pg_BuildReport_lstFeatures_1" type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="ctl00$pg$BuildReport$lstFeatures$1">
   <label for="ctl00_pg_BuildReport_lstFeatures_1">Member Information</label>
</td>
```

It's the same framework on both projects (3.5) the only difference is the main project has a masterpage, and maybe some extra panels, but I just wondered what would stop the span on getting rendered? Any help would be useful. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this and see if it has any effect:

```
item.Attributes.CssStyle.Add("margin-left", String.Format("{0}px", margin));
```

Comment: As for your specific question about why it might be different between the two environments, I would double check that the same service pack is being used, and, I don't think this matters, but for giggles I'd also be curious as to whether or not both applications are using the same HTML/XHTML doctype.

Comment: Adding it by CssStyle didn't work either. If it helps I am running one app under my own localhost (using the inbuilt ASP.NET Development server, this displays correctly) and the other under windows 2008 IIS 6 server (this doesn't display the style)